# GNUPLOT LINUX Value y-axis near every point of a graph

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot, histogram, point

I need to do a graph with gnoplot linux where on x-axis there are a date and on y-axis value of ok, ko and warning.
I've written the following code

```
    #!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset

unset title
set xlabel "Date (day/month)"
set ylabel "num Instance"
set yrange [0:40]

set term png large
set output "graph2.png"

set grid

set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m"
set format x "%d/%m"

plot \
'input.dat' using 1:2 with points pointtype 11 linecolor rgb "#00FF00" ti 'OK',\
'input.dat' using 1:3 with points pointtype 11 linecolor rgb "#ff0000" ti 'KO',\
'input.dat' using 1:4 with points pointtype 3 linecolor rgb "#ffed00" ti 'Warning'
```

with this input file

```
#date   ok  ko  warning
06/02   1  30  3
07/02   5  14  16
08/02   30  15  14
09/02   9  14  9
10/02   7  30  3
11/02   2  7  21
12/02   30  12  15
13/02   10  15  14
14/02   24  14  16
15/02   20  12  15
```

and the graph is this

[new_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpcCw.jpg)

Now I've to insert, near every point, also a value of y-axis.

Any idea?
I appreciate your help and thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at [gnuplot histogram label values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310921/add-y-axis-value-labels-to-gnuplot-bar-chart). They use a trick to make a second plot printing those values. [gnuplot-surprising.blogspot](https://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-value-labels-to-top-of-bars-in-bar.html) may be a better explanation

Comment: I modified the initial request. I hope to have been clear. thank you

Comment: No, you are not clear. Now you have two questions in one. It the part with the points is a new question, then please ask a new question. If you want points instead of a histogram, edit this question by removing obsolete parts.

Comment: thank's Christoph...I've modify my question. I hope its good now! :-)